# Comparison of strings will not return true, even tough they are identical

Tags: mysql, processing

I am currently creating a super simple login system for educational purpose only in Processing.

What i am doing in short is comparing the inputs from 2 textfields created with the controllerP5-library, with information from a MySQL database which i am using the BezierSQlib-library to connect to. All of the code is contained in a method inside a class called DbHandler which has all of the code which is related to the database.

But the final if statement where i compare the retrieved password from the database with the password that is inputted by the user will not work. Even though the 2 strings are identical they it will not return true. I´ve tried just putting in " if('1234 == '1234')" and that returned true.

But if i do it like so "if(_rPass == '1234')" with the _rPass being the password from the database, and the password being set to 1234 it still returns false.

```
void loginCheck(String name, String password){ //This is the method that checks if the login information is correct
String _rPass; //where we store the retrieved password from the database

if(_msql.connect()){ //if there´s connection to the database 
  println("connection"); //we write out there´s a connection in the prompt

 _msql.query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='" + name + "'"); //a query is done to find the matching password to the username

 _msql.next(); //selects the next row in the retrieved table

    if(_msql.getString(1) == null){ //if there´s no user with that username in the user table
      println("wrong username"); //the username must be wrong
    } //end if
    else{ //if something is returned!

        _rPass = _msql.getString(1); //the password from the database is stored in _rPass

        if(_rPass == password) { //!!!THIS WILL NOT RETURN TRUE NO MATTER WHAT!!!
          println("succesfull login!"); //if the strings are the same we´re logged in!
        }

        else{
          println("wrong password");
        }
    }
}
```

}

The following code is a part of a "DbHandler" class which controls all of the code that is related to the database, and is being called in another class called "interface" through a method.

The part where the above method is activated is like so:

```
      if(btn_login.isPositionWithinButton(mouseX,mouseY)){ //checks if the login button has been clicked
    DbHandler.loginCheck( cp5.get(Textfield.class,"username").getText(), cp5.get(Textfield.class,"password").getText() ); //the loginCheck method is called with the arguments being the text from the textFields
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string. equal method instead of ==.

As == compares the reference so it will return false if reference is not same.

To compare value of string use equal method.

i. e.   If (_rpass.equals(password)){}